# Адаптивность блока с годами

Tags: html, css

Вся верстка с мобилок смотрится нормально, кроме блока с годами, подскажите,каким способом поправить?

```css
.y2011{
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 120px;
 margin-left: 30px;
}
 .year2011{
  font-size: 48pt;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
 }
  .year_text{
   padding-top: 20px;
   font-size: 15pt;
   color: #888888;
  }
.y2012{
 margin-left: 770px;
 margin-top: 220px;
}
 .year2012{
  text-align: left;
 }
.y2013{
 margin-top: 480px;
}
.y2014{
 margin-top: 700px;
 text-align: left;
}
 .year2014{
  text-align: left;
 }
#f_img{
 margin-top:-220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="history_of_team">
    <div class="y2011">
     <p class="year2011">2011</p>
     <p class="year_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiselit. Vivamus <br/>varius nec diam vitae hendrerit bigus mit.</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="y2011 y2012">
     <p class="year2011 year2012">2012</p>
     <p class="year_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiselit. Vivamus<br/> varius nec diam vitae hendrerit bigus mit.<br/>Begitus vit urna nulla.</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="y2011 y2013">
     <p class="year2011 year2013">2013</p>
     <p class="year_text">Sed at auctor sem, nec tincidunt elit. Pellentesque enim<br/> turpis, porttitor ac orci in, ultrices efficitur nisl. Ut odio libero,<br/> sodales a tellus eleifend, suscipit dapibus mi.</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="y2011 y2012 y2014">
     <p class="year2011 year2014">2014</p>
     <p class="year_text">Sed at auctor sem, nec tincidunt elit. Pellentesque enim<br/> turpis, porttitor ac orci in, ultrices efficitur nisl. Ut odio libero,<br/> sodales a tellus eleifend, suscipit dapibus mi.</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="img">
     <img src="img/main-line.png" alt="123">
     <img id="f_img" src="img/background-city.png" alt="">
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.history_of_team {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, auto));
  grid-gap: 100px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.history_of_team>div {
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 15pt;
  color: #888888;
}
```

```html
<div class="history_of_team">
  <div class="y2011">
    <p class="year2011">2011</p>
    <p class="year_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiselit. Vivamus <br/>varius nec diam vitae hendrerit bigus mit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="y2011 y2012">
    <p class="year2011 year2012">2012</p>
    <p class="year_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiselit. Vivamus<br/> varius nec diam vitae hendrerit bigus mit.<br/>Begitus vit urna nulla.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="y2011 y2013">
    <p class="year2011 year2013">2013</p>
    <p class="year_text">Sed at auctor sem, nec tincidunt elit. Pellentesque enim<br/> turpis, porttitor ac orci in, ultrices efficitur nisl. Ut odio libero,<br/> sodales a tellus eleifend, suscipit dapibus mi.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="y2011 y2012 y2014">
    <p class="year2011 year2014">2014</p>
    <p class="year_text">Sed at auctor sem, nec tincidunt elit. Pellentesque enim<br/> turpis, porttitor ac orci in, ultrices efficitur nisl. Ut odio libero,<br/> sodales a tellus eleifend, suscipit dapibus mi.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="img/main-line.png" alt="123">
    <img id="f_img" src="img/background-city.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Возможно так...

Comment: Не-а оно все слипляется и вытесняет картинку по центру

Comment: @Aleksandr Yakovlev, можно картинку как должно быть?

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c858216/v858216480/1f1e8/qY8uyQn6RNI.jpg

Comment: @peter есть еще идеи поповодуэтого?